# How do I interpret the output of Mac's 'sample' tool

Tags: mac, macos

I have a process that is running on OS X which has some problems and the 'sample' tool on the Mac seems like the best way to debug the problem. Unfortunately, the only documentation I can find for it is the man page which says nothing about how to interpret the results.

Are there any good places that document the output and how to interpret it? If not, can someone give me a very basic tutorial?

Comment: If you don't understand the output, how do you know it is the right tool? If it is a performance issue, sample might help, but I would recommend using Instruments from inside xcode instead. The sample manpage suggests finding it in /Developer/... That is obsolete. Run Xcode, and find Instruments in the menus: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Instruments.

Answer (score 6):

I just checked the Man page on [*sample*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html)
and it looks to me like a half-decent call-stack sampler.
It claims that its output is the call-tree, so that should not be too hard to comprehend.

I say half-decent because collecting call-stack samples is a good thing. The criticisms are:

1. It doesn't say if it collects samples when the process is in a system call, like waiting for I/O. It is important to do so, unless you want to be blind to needless I/O.
2. It falls for the fiction that [*what matters is accuracy of timing and you don't want to miss any functions, so samples have to be really frequent*](http://archive.today/9r927). It's a fiction because the goal is to *find* big stuff, not to *measure* little stuff. Any function that doesn't appear certainly doesn't cost enough to care about.
   The consequence of this fiction is there are too many samples for you to look at, so it has to try to find a way to summarize them, so it chooses a call-tree. The fact is, if you are allowed to actually *examine a small number of the samples* (like 10 or 20) you will see exactly the reason(s) for the slowness. The summarization is the problem. It smears out and hides the information.

So, the long-and-short is, it appears to be a good tool for collecting call-stack samples.
If you can figure out how to actually see a selection of them, it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Has anyone come up with a better way to view these samples in recent years? I'm having a devil of a time with a particular hang issue and need to review a number of samples, but, as @Mike Dunlavey explains, it's still pretty rough to get to the core issue quickly. It seems that digging about within the Instruments tool is a bit time consuming and so some more meaningful summary mechanism from the shell would be most useful.

Comment: @ylluminate: Sorry I didn't see your comment until now. The thing is, the worse your performance problem is, the easier it should be to find. For a hard hang, you should just be able to Ctrl-C or pause it under the debugger, while it is hung, and it will stop in whatever the problem is, guaranteed. If you don't trust the answer, try it several times. That's how I do it. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your input there, unfortunately this is happening on non-dev apps that I'm running and so they're not generally executed within the debugger. I'm hunting down problems for apps where I'm capturing sample data in the shell during the app hangs.

Comment: @ylluminate: Lack of a debugger makes things more difficult. I've faced this along the way. Any way you can grab one or a small number of stack samples during the hang? Profilers mostly seem to operate under the assumption that you need lots of samples, summarized. Maybe the doc on the profiler will tell you how to see the actual stack samples themselves, not summarized? Then you can pick a few at random to examine. That's what I look for.